# JMeter with MQTT how to count Ramp-up-period(Seconds)

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, load-testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfljJ.png) - I want to test with JMeter to MQTT for load Testing.

- I tried with appliance on/off using JMeter to MQTT it working But i need to clarify
  with
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfljJ.png)how to count Ramp-up-period(Seconds) when i connect with appliances.

  **For example
  Number of Threads (Users)=10
  Ramp-up-period(Seconds)=5
  loop count=1**

i used the formula for Ramp-up-period(Seconds)= i need 0.5 second
for each thread *for 10 user =5 Second it is correct formula for
Ramp-up-period(Seconds) MQTT using with appliances on and off
command

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" formula.

[Official user manual says](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed**.

The main idea is to increase the load **gradually** because if there is a problem with 10 simulated appliances you can state only that the broker cannot support 10 devices, you won't have the answer where the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) is, where the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) is and won't be able to correlate increasing load with other metrics like response times and throughput.

You might also want to increase the number of loops because it might be the case that some threads have already finished their work and were shut down and some of them hasn't started yet (unless this is the behaviour you're looking for)

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)